# How to make changes to other components with same name without affecting the current component

Tags: angular

Inside my user component i'm using 4 user-data component to display 4 different data for the user.Now,inside my user-data component there is a div which is only visible if the local variable isEdit is true.Now when,div inside on user-data is visible the other should not be visible.How do i do this i.e. a once one div is visible all other div's should hide in other components without affecting the current component?

```
<div class="user-detail" >
 <div class="user-action" *ngIf="isEdit">
 <label>Aeshna <i (click)="add()" class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
 <div>
    <i (click)="selected()" class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    <p>Add user</p> 
 </div>
</div>

 <img (click)="click()" [ngStyle]="{'width': width}" src="../../../../assets/images/user/{{orientation}}/{{user}}.svg">
</div>
```

this is my user-detail.The click() function makes isEdit true

Comment: is it like only one div should be visible at a time ?

Comment: yes..there is one image inside all the 4 components which on clicking displays the div for which i'm using isEdit.But the problem is,isEdit is not changing for other 3 components due to which they are still visible

Comment: can you provide bit of a code?

Comment: so each image click should display their corresponding divs?

Comment: looks like you need service across all user-data components which maintains a variable (array of 4) indiacting what component should be visible.

Comment: @DeepakVerma yes

Comment: @AniketChopade ya but the problem is i don't know how may user-details component will be there.Here as an example i said 4.There can be many other depending on the list of users present

Comment: try making a function toggleDetails(){ isEdit = !IsEdit} this will toggle your div

Comment: @DeepakVerma but this wont change isEdit for other components.It will only toggle it for the current component

Comment: why don't you put the condition as *ngIf='!isEdit' for the other div which should not be visible so that if one div is visible other will be hidden as condition counts to be false for them

Comment: @DeepakVerma but it belongs in other component.So if i change isEdit in one it won't affect the other component

Answer (score 0):

you create an rxjs subject on click / event.  send the id of the active one and creeate an observer or observers to listen  it, and that function keep that specic id open and closes the rest (or whatever logic you want) or every item listens for itself and behavious individual

Answer (score 0):

you can archive this by creating a message service

here is the example

message service:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlagService {
getFlag() : Observable<any> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
setFlag(result:Code){
  this.subject.next({ text: code });
}
```

Component where you set the flag for isEdit

```
export class componentOne OnInit {
constructor(private service: FlagService ){}
sendDataToMessageService(){
  this.isEdit = true; // this need to be dynamically changed based on your condition
  this.service.setFlag(this.isEdit);
}
```

the component which are you using 4 times

```
export class otherComponent OnInit {
constructor(private service: FlagService ){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.service.getFlag().subscribe(response => {
    this.isEdit = response // here you can get updated data of your variable isEdit from the component where you set the isEdit value 
 });
```

}

I hope it helps

Comment: All the 4 components are same not different.I have used the same component inside user component 4 times

Comment: so basically you have 2 component one component where the isEdit is being change and other component where you want to get the isEdit data am i right?

Comment: ya 2 components.Inside the 1st component i'm using the second component 4 times.So if isEdit is true for one of the 4 same component it should be false for all others

Comment: okay got it so you need to implement message service which i already write in answer section but this code you need to write in the component which are you using 4 times (ngOnInit(){
   this.service.getFlag().subscribe(response => {
    this.isEdit = response // here you can get updated data of your variable isEdit from the component where you set the isEdit value 
 });)

Comment: But i set the isEdit in the same component from where will i call getFlag()

Comment: Check the code.There is an image which has a click event and that function changes isEdit and that isEdit is being used by the other div above the image not some other component

Comment: On image click  function you need to set the flag this.service.setFlag(this.isEdit); and other component you need to subscribe that service i already write that code in answer

Comment: here is the example link from medium :  https://medium.com/instarem-engineering/subjects-in-angular-2-4-5-4e5986e38e47

Comment: But the other component i.e the parent is not using isEdit.The only one using it is e child components which is all same but is used 4 times